# Pixate Button Shadow Android

Tags: android, css, pixate

Pixate's documentation says that a button can have a box-shadow.

http://pixate.github.io/pixate-freestyle-android/style-reference/controls/button.html

However, I have tried all sorts of variations of the following with no luck.  I have also tried this with views, and no joy.

`button { box-shadow : 3px 3px #000000; }`

Has anybody managed to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one param:

```
button { box-shadow : 3px 3px 0 #000000; }
```